# Google Maps JavaScript API: How to remove individual marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay

I'm using the Google Maps v3 library, with the [Multi-Marker](http://code.google.com/p/multimarker/source/browse/trunk/fast-marker-overlay/maps-v3/src/FastMarkerOverlay.js) library which extends the functionality of Google Maps for super fast adding of map marker icons to a map.

I can't figure out how to remove a **single**, individual map marker using the multi-marker library linked above.

Does anyone have any ideas how I'd do this using the multi-marker library (and/or Google Maps)? I've tried contacting the lead developer of the project but am not getting a response.

Thanks for any help.

Also, linked is more information on this library

```
http://blog.redfin.com/devblog/2010/07/introducing_multimarker_the_fastest_way_to_add_many_hundreds_or_thousands_of_markers_on_google_maps.html
```

**UPDATE**:

I have linked example code of what I'm doing. I want to dynamically remove specific map marker icons (overlays) but am struggling on how to do that. Any advise would be very appreciated. Thanks

Live example:

```
http://multimarker.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fast-marker-overlay/maps-v3/example/clickable.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Normaly, using only the google maps api, to remove an overlay from the map you would need to call the setMap(null) method on the overlay.

As I can see, the Multi-Marker library uses an array to hold all the markers and creates an overlay to show on the map, an overlay that contains the markers. To remove one, it should work to remove the marker from the array (you need to know its position in the array) and redraw the overlay.

Edit:

You need something similar to  function clearOverlays() { var i = overlays.length; while (i--) { var overlay = overlays[i]; if (overlay) overlay.setMap(null); delete overlays[i]; } }

But you'll need to know the position in the array of the marker you want to delete. The function will look like this:

```
 function clearOneOverlay(var position) { var overlay = overlays[position]; if (overlay) overlay.setMap(null); delete overlays[position]; }
```

Comment: thanks. That make sense but I'm struggling to figure out how I'd update the example code linked here to allow me to remove a specific marker dynamically --> http://multimarker.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fast-marker-overlay/maps-v3/example/clickable.html

You might helping by looking at this example code and provide some suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: You need a function similar to function clearOverlays() {
    var i = overlays.length;
    while (i--) {
      var overlay = overlays[i];
      if (overlay) overlay.setMap(null);
      delete overlays[i];
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

try this: remember which marker you click and then remove it later

consider following code(Google Maps v2)

```
var current_marker;

GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          current_marker = marker;
      });

//remove later
current_marker.setMap(null);
```