# How to add address to a google map on web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a web app. One of the page is designed to show google map of an address traced from database. So after I get langitude and latitude using gencode, I know how to draw the google map, but how do I show an address tag on that map? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do u mean by address tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably talking about a `Marker` concept.

Take a look at this [article](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/07/google-maps-api-3-markers/)

A couple of other SO folks asked similar questions. These might be helpful:
[Draggable markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322613/how-to-add-draggable-markers-to-a-google-map-using-jquery)

While this may be OT, if you ever decide to *remove* a marker, also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159505/google-maps-javascript-api-how-to-remove-individual-marker)

There is also detailed Marker docs available at the [usual API docs site](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker)